# Is it possible to prohibit the mount command prompt the password hint?

Tags: ubuntu, mount, samba

I need to mount a samba share directory on Ubuntu 16.04. Although the samba share directory(served by a Ubuntu 12.04 machine) has no password protection, the mount command still prompts the password hint:

```
# mount //10.117.47.250/view ~/target
Password for root@/10.117.47.250/view:
```

To my surprise, it will mount the samba share directory successfully whatever I input after the password hint.

I found a solution that can disappear the password hint:

```
mount -o password= //10.117.47.250/view ~/target
```

Is there other solution can prohibit the password hint prompt?

Comment: Does this problem persist when you try it as a normal user?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to have an entry in your `/etc/fstab` like:

```
//10.117.47.250/view /root/target cifs username=root,password=,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm  0  0
```

After that you should/would be able to mount it:

```
mount ~/target
```

In the above example anybody can see the password in `/etc/fstab`. It can be prevented by having the password in another file `/etc/nsmb.conf`:

```
[10.117.47.250:root]
password=
```